# boto initiate_multipart_upload fails with signature mismatch

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm currently trying to use [cassandra_snapshotter](https://github.com/tbarbugli/cassandra_snapshotter/blob/master/cassandra_snapshotter/agent.py) with cloud storage in interoperability mode. However event the first request to upload a file fails with a signature mismatch.

Did a small testcase, as even the first request is failing:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

connection = S3Connection(
    aws_access_key_id='GOOGY',
    aws_secret_access_key='SECRET',
    host='storage.googleapis.com'
)
bucket = connection.get_bucket('foo-cassandra-backups', validate=False)

mp = bucket.initiate_multipart_upload('/g/mnt/cassandra-data2/data/bar/baz-63b205e0618711e7a41cf5e393c7464c/snapshots/20170705150900/manifest.json.lzo')
```

This fails with:

```
send: 'POST /g/mnt/cassandra-data2/data/foo/threshold-63b205e0618711e7a41cf5e393c7464c/snapshots/20170705150900/manifest.json.lzo?uploads HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: blubb-cassandra-backups.storage.googleapis.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nDate: Thu, 06 Jul 2017 11:18:46 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nAuthorization: AWS BLUBB:F6Ml3vSzDphY7UTGNuf3m+fe19I=\r\nUser-Agent: Boto/2.47.0 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.4.0-83-generic\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n'
header: X-GUploader-UploadID: BLUBB
header: Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
header: Content-Length: 447
header: Vary: Origin
header: Date: Thu, 06 Jul 2017 11:18:46 GMT
header: Server: UploadServer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 11, in <module>
    mp = bucket.initiate_multipart_upload('/g/mnt/cassandra-data2/data/foo/threshold-63b205e0618711e7a41cf5e393c7464c/snapshots/20170705150900/manifest.json.lzo')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 1767, in initiate_multipart_upload
    response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>POST


Thu, 06 Jul 2017 11:18:46 GMT
/blubb-cassandra-backups/g/mnt/cassandra-data2/data/foo/threshold-63b205e0618711e7a41cf5e393c7464c/snapshots/20170705150900/manifest.json.lzo</StringToSign></Error>
```

So i guess the API is not compatible in this case and i'm relatively lost here on how to properly fix it. Additionally i'd like to avoid big changes to the uploader, as we would need to deploy the patches as well.

**EDIT**: This is with boto 2.47 and i guess it's because AWS requires the `?uploads` param but googles API is different and therefore it's not expected in the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not support the multi-part upload feature of the S3 API, so I would suggest using the regular upload approach (ex. [set_contents_from_file()](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/af045f93d70fbb4cdac2a8e57d040ce59935d45b/boto/s3/key.py#L1131)).